# Spring Annotation Mapping Case Insensitive

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, annotations, mapping

I am using Spring 3 annotation requestmapping and I was wondering how I can map my paths so they are case INsensitive.  I am using Tomcat 6.

I found this question on SO but no answers.

[How can I have case insensitive URLS in Spring MVC with annotated mappings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150039/how-can-i-have-case-insensitive-urls-in-spring-mvc-with-annotated-mappings)

An exmaple of my mapping on my local would be:

http://localhost:8080/myproject/web/us/arizona/test.html

The state is a parameter and is working regardless of case.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: If the question has already been asked, then you shouldn't ask it again. Try opening a bounty on the original question, to encourage answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I have case insensitive URLS in Spring MVC with annotated mappings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150039/how-can-i-have-case-insensitive-urls-in-spring-mvc-with-annotated-mappings)