# How to check whether the Query String name coming from URL with @RequestParam name are equal (case sensitive)

Tags: java, spring

I have problem on checking equals between query string from url to request param name.

For example providing the status attribute in `Postman` will be as below:

**`http:localhost:8080/foo?Status=COMPLETED`**

But the controller method has the following:

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/foo")
@ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.OK)
public void getSomething(@RequestParam(name="status") Optional<Enum[]> status) {
    //Something
}
```

*Expected Solution:*
The param name provided in url should match the `@RequestParam(name="status")` which is case sensitive.

Note: This is purely a Spring project (even no spring-web-mvc) - no usages of Spring Boot and Hibernate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RequestParam value in spring MVC to be case insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8922371/requestparam-value-in-spring-mvc-to-be-case-insensitive)

Comment: I dont think case insensitivity is supported for that. You could however map all parameters like so `@RequestParam Map<String,String> allParams` and then check if the keyset contains the string you are looking for. Though you will have to use a TreeMap and the String CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER

Comment: i dont think this is really recommended as its like jumping through hoops when you can just ensure your client and server follows same standards

Comment: @experimentunit1998X I have lots of controller so this requires to handle for all request param names which is hectic one- do we have any common way or predefined way to handle this

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Spring's `@RequestParam` is case sensitive, and
rewriting the controllers to avoid that would be a fair amount of work.

###### So, instead, you can do this by adding a servlet filter:

In your case the variable is `status`, so for every request it will convert it as per your variable setter method camel case injection and then match as per your request.

Just try for your custom requirements:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32525732/2039546

Comment: It is not Spring that is case sensitive but the servlet API. `status` and `Status` are different parameters according to that.