# case insensitive mapping for Spring MVC @RequestMapping annotations

Tags: java, web-applications, spring-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I have case insensitive URLS in Spring MVC with annotated mappings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150039/how-can-i-have-case-insensitive-urls-in-spring-mvc-with-annotated-mappings)

I have Controller having multiple @RequestMapping annotations in it.

```
@Controller
public class SignUpController {

 @RequestMapping("signup")
 public String showSignUp() throws Exception {
    return "somejsp";
 }

 @RequestMapping("fullSignup")
 public String showFullSignUp() throws Exception {
    return "anotherjsp";
 }

 @RequestMapping("signup/createAccount")
 public String createAccount() throws Exception {
    return "anyjsp";
 }
}
```

How can I map these @RequestMapping to case insensitive. i.e. if I use "/fullsignup" or "/fullSignup" I should get "anotherjsp". But this is not happening right now. Only "/fullSignup" is working fine.

I've tried extending RequestMappingHandlerMapping but no success. I've also tried AntPathMatcher like the guy mentioned there is another question on this forum but its also not working for @RequestMapping annotation.

Debugging console
[image]

Output console when server is up.

[image]

I've added two images which shows the problem. I've tried both the solutions mentioned below. The console says that it mapped lowercased URLS but when I request to access a method with lowercase url then it shows that the original map where the values are stored stilled contained MixCase URLS.

Comment: I'll refer you to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150039/how-can-i-have-case-insensitive-urls-in-spring-mvc-with-annotated-mappings

Comment: @gtgaxiola no this has nothing to do with RequestMapping. This works for Controller annotation only. I've tried this.

Comment: Both answers are correct but with different approach. Whatever you choose. Depending upon urself.

Comment: I know that its a duplicate but this have clear and detailed explanation. Which I was unable to find on that duplicate question. Thats why I offered bounty on this question. If the duplicated question was correct one why would I do that

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One of the approaches in [How can I have case insensitive URLS in Spring MVC with annotated mappings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150039/how-can-i-have-case-insensitive-urls-in-spring-mvc-with-annotated-mappings) works perfectly. I just tried it with combinations of @RequestMapping at the level of controller and request methods and it has worked cleanly, I am just reproducing it here for Spring 3.1.2:

The CaseInsensitivePathMatcher:

```
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.util.AntPathMatcher;

public class CaseInsensitivePathMatcher extends AntPathMatcher {
    @Override
    protected boolean doMatch(String pattern, String path, boolean fullMatch, Map<String, String> uriTemplateVariables) {
        return super.doMatch(pattern.toLowerCase(), path.toLowerCase(), fullMatch, uriTemplateVariables);
    }
}
```

Registering this path matcher with Spring MVC, remove the `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` annotation, and replace with the following, configure appropriately:

```
<bean name="handlerAdapter" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="webBindingInitializer">
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.bind.support.ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer">
            <property name="conversionService" ref="conversionService"></property>
            <property name="validator">
                <bean class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
                    <property name="providerClass" value="org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator"></property>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="byteArrayConverter"/>
            <ref bean="jaxbConverter"/>
            <ref bean="jsonConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.XmlAwareFormHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean name="byteArrayConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
<bean name="jaxbConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
<bean name="jsonConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"></bean>
<bean name="caseInsensitivePathMatcher" class="org.bk.lmt.web.spring.CaseInsensitivePathMatcher"/>
<bean name="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping">
    <property name="pathMatcher" ref="caseInsensitivePathMatcher"></property>
</bean>
```

Or even more easily and cleanly using @Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="org.bk.webtestuuid")
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport{

    @Bean
    public PathMatcher pathMatcher(){
        return new CaseInsensitivePathMatcher();
    }
    @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
        RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping = new RequestMappingHandlerMapping();
        handlerMapping.setOrder(0);
        handlerMapping.setInterceptors(getInterceptors());
        handlerMapping.setPathMatcher(pathMatcher());
        return handlerMapping;
    }
}
```

Comment: can u please see my edited question

Comment: Thanks man for your time. This is really appreciable.

Comment: This solution also affected query parameters, which was a problem for us. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31700674/401712) for a  better solution with Spring 4.2.

Answer (score 4):

The following simple solution should make @RequestMapping insensitive, whether it annotates a Controller or a method. Biju's solution should work too.

Create this custom HandlerMapping :

```
public CaseInsensitiveAnnotationHandlerMapping extends DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping {

    @Override
    protected Object lookupHandler(String urlPath, HttpServletRequest request)
                    throws Exception {

        return super.lookupHandler(urlPath.toLowerCase(), request);
    }

    @Override
    protected void registerHandler(String urlPath, Object handler)
                    throws BeansException, IllegalStateException {

        super.registerHandler(urlPath.toLowerCase(), handler);
    }

}
```

And add this in your  *[servlet-name]*-servlet.xml :

```
<bean class="yourpackage.CaseInsensitiveAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
```

Note: if you don't want two HandlerMapping in your app, you may want to remove `<mvc:annotation-driven />` (it instantiates a `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping`).

Comment: can u please see my edited question

Comment: @ZahidRiaz have you tried removing <mvc:annotation-driven /> ?

Comment: I've tried But I got this error?

javax.servlet.ServletException: No adapter for handler [net.hrms.web.controller.SignUpController@6f70829e]: Does your handler implement a supported interface like Controller?

Comment: @ZahidRiaz When you remove `<mvc:annotation-driven>`, you must replace it by the usual beans it instantiates. See [this link (click here)](https://gist.github.com/861863) : just replace `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` by `CaseInsensitiveAnnotationHandlerMapping` in the xml.

Comment: This will did the trick. +1 for different solution. Thanks man. You save the day

Comment: @ZahidRiaz: Hi so where does the custom handler mapping go exactly? Do you put it in the the mycontroller.java file or a separate handlermapping.java file or somewhere else?

Comment: @JaJ Create a new java file and add the entry of that file like mentioned in answer.

Comment: @ZahidRiaz: so it looks like DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping is deprecated in spring 3.2.2. what is the alternative to this class?