# How to match context path case insentively in Spring MVC 4

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm building an application in Spring MVC 4.0.1, and I have case insensitive URL matching working but only for the part of the path that's below the context path. I.E. "localhost:8080/app/test.html" and "localhost:8080/app/TeSt.html" both route to the same page.

Trick is I would also like to be able to do this for the context path "/app".

I'm running the app from Jetty 9 and Glassfish 4, and will probably add Tomcat by the end to satisfy all customers who will end up running it, so I would really prefer to have the setting in Spring rather than higher up.

In Jetty 9, when I do case insensitive path matching, anything other than the default context path invalidates the session and logs the user out of the application.

Is this possible as a configuration in Spring MVC? If it is, how?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684183/case-insensitive-mapping-for-spring-mvc-requestmapping-annotations

Comment: @Blithe yes, I have that working, all annotation driven paths are matching case insensitively. It's the context path, the root path for the application that I want to have match case insensitively.

Comment: Maybe I'm just using the wrong word for what I'm trying to do, and this is causing google to never return what I'm looking for.

Comment: Looks like it's not possible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664059/how-do-you-specify-the-root-context-in-your-web-app-tags-in-web-xml/664089#664089

Comment: I'm having the same issue where I want the root context to be case insensitive. Tried server configuration as well. Nothing worked.