# I need to redirect my https url to lowercase using spring?

Tags: spring-mvc

I need to redirect my https url to lowercase using spring 
how to do that kindly any one suggest solution ..

I follow the steps on following url, it doesn't work for me.

[How can I have case insensitive URLS in Spring MVC with annotated mappings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150039/how-can-i-have-case-insensitive-urls-in-spring-mvc-with-annotated-mappings)

What I need is: if I type STACKOVERFLOW.COM and enter mean it redirect to stackoverflow.com but the above url steps did not meet what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is already a lot of question related to this I think you could easily find a solution here : https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13286

there is also another question on stackoverflow here :
[case insensitive mapping for Spring MVC @RequestMapping annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684183/case-insensitive-mapping-for-spring-mvc-requestmapping-annotations)

To modify dynamic URL's you could transform it when you get it in the code with a `.toLowerCase()` when you recieve it.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: thanks .. it works for static urls . 
but for dynamic urls it does not work.

Comment: where do you enter your dynamic url ? you get it in your code no ? you could transform it when you get it with a .toLowerCase() when you recieve it

Comment: @EmCode He meant if there is anything to do this that framework already provides or some regex or annotation while receiving it in code