# Is there any way we make PathVariable name case insensitive in Spring?

Tags: spring-mvc

I have an URI `https://localhost/Message/message?id=10` and it will give the message details with id=10.

I want to get the same response when I entered the URI as below (here path variable is with different case)

```
 https://localhost/Message/message?id=10 
 https://localhost/Message/Message?ID=10 
 https://localhost/Message/mEssage?Id=10 
 https://localhost/Message/MESSAGE?iD=10
```

Comment: Follow the answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/12732550/4423636

Answer (score 3):

**For the URI/PathVariable (Message) name:** 
[Spring 4.2+](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13286) supports configuration of case-insensitive path matching.
You can configure it as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        AntPathMatcher matcher = new AntPathMatcher();
        matcher.setCaseSensitive(false);
        configurer.setPathMatcher(matcher);
    }
}
```

**For the `@RequestParam`/request parameters (ID) part:**

You have to do it manually - there's no support in Spring Boot for this out of the box. The base concept is that you have to implement a custom servlet filter, which standardizes the params in `HttpServletRequest` - e.g. you can apply to all of them `String.toLowerCase()` before passing them down to your `@RestController`, where you have all the request parameter binding defined as lower-cased values.

Comment: The `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` has been deprecated in spring 5. is there any spring 5 compatible way of doing this?

Comment: @UroshT.yes - they deprecated the abstract adapter class in favour of default methods in the interface - just use the interface WebMvcConfigurer.