# SpringMVC - Naming strategy for @RequestParam

Tags: java, spring

I would like all my APIs to use lower-case request parameters, but I would still like to use camel-case in my Java code.

For example, consider the following code:

```
@GetMapping("/ping")
public String ping(
    String responseMessage)
{
    return "PONG " + responseMessage;
}
```

To contact this endpoint and supply a response message, I would have to call: `localhost:8080/ping?responseMessage=Hello`. However, I would like spring to automatically bind the variable name `responseMessage` to a request parameter named `responsemessage`. I specifically do not want to manually write  `@RequestParam(name="responsemessage")` in my controller, but rather configure a global naming strategy for request parameters. Is this possible?

There are a couple of other threads on SO that talks about making the request parameters or url mappings case-insensitive:

- [RequestParam value in spring MVC to be case insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8922371/1943559)
- [Is there any way we make PathVariable name case insensitive in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49228615/1943559)
- [Spring mvc. case insensitive get parameters mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32364126/1943559)
- [Making a request parameter binding case insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29531786/1943559)

However, the answers in these questions strikes me as quite hacky or requires manual codeing. Is there no simple setting for the behaviour I am after? I know this is possible when using JSON bodies, by configuring the Jackson propertyNamingStrategy. Is there an equivalent for request parameters?

Comment: This thread might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29531786/making-a-request-parameter-binding-case-insensitive