# Spring Boot 1.5.8 URL Case Insensitive Configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot

In Spring Boot 1.5.8, I want to setup all of my `RestController`s' URLs to be case insensitive.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29810228/7506662) is a programmatic solution on Stackoverflow.

I just wonder is there any kinds of configuration we could setup in application.properties (or in other Spring Boot's configuration file)?
Unfortunately, I don't find any flags in [Spring Boot's Appendix A](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html#common-application-properties).

Could we configure the URL to be case-insensitive in Spring Boot?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @Arya as mentioned in the post, there is a programmatic way. So far I haven't found any configuration for it.

Answer (score -1):

If it's a Spring Boot application you can have this in your application.properties file:

```
spring.jackson.mapper.accept_case_insensitive_properties=true
```

Comment: @Macro this only makes the JSON payload case insensitive. What I was asking is make the *URL* case insensitive.