# Not all endpoints exposed, despite from the same controller

Tags: spring-boot, http-status-code-404, spring-restcontroller

I have the following controller in my Spring Boot application :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/users")
public class UserController {

@Autowired
UserService userService;

@GetMapping(value ="/helloWorld")
public String getHelloWorld() {
    return "Hello World!";
}

@GetMapping(value = "/getAll")
public @ResponseBody
Iterable<User> getAllInvestors() {
    return userService.getAllUsers();
}
}
```

When I make an HTTP Get on `http://127.0.0.1:5000/users/getAll`, it works perfectly : I get all the users from the database...

but when I make a call on `http://127.0.0.1:5000/users/helloWorld`, I get an `unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404)`

- PS 1 : When I call `http://127.0.0.1:5000/api-docs` to get the API definition : Both endpoints are exposed.
- PS 2 : I've already made a Maven Clean, restarted IntelliJ, deleted all cookies from the browser.
- PS 3 : No errors during compilation.

Comment: How is the request made ? From browser or through code ?

Comment: From the browser, Google chrome.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the case sensitivity, it was solved when I replaced `@GetMapping(value ="/helloWorld")` with `@GetMapping(value ="/helloworld")`

[Refer to this topic for further details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150039/how-can-i-have-case-insensitive-urls-in-spring-mvc-with-annotated-mappings)

Comment: The details given in the question is actually correct. The issue was with the way you were making the request , nothing code related ( `getAll` works )