# In spring boot localhost not taking data when program is running fine on console

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, local, host

I am learning spring boot and trying to built my first application. Program is running fine on console. When I'm trying to add data on localhost page showing error?
[Alien.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAa0P.png)

[home.jsp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtr5s.png)

[AlienController.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DC2tb.png)

[BoojApplication.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Fwfp.png)

[AlienRepo.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/614ak.png)

[application.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHuIv.png)

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEkvt.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nl6TW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is clear: `404` means Spring didn't find your URL.

Your controller declares `addAlien` with an uppercase, while your test uses `addalien` with a lowercase.

Make sure to be consistent everywhere with your declarations and your usages.

For more informations, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150039/how-can-i-have-case-insensitive-urls-in-spring-mvc-with-annotated-mappings).