# Spring Boot 2.6.7 URL case insensitive configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot

In Spring Boot 2.6.7, I want to set up all of my controllers' URLs to be case-insensitive.

I tried this but it does not work

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        AntPathMatcher matcher = new AntPathMatcher();
        matcher.setCaseSensitive(false);
        configurer.setPathMatcher(matcher);
    }
}
```

Can we configure it through application.properties file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I have case insensitive URLS in Spring MVC with annotated mappings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150039/how-can-i-have-case-insensitive-urls-in-spring-mvc-with-annotated-mappings)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You want case **in**sensitive but you call matcher.setCaseSensitive(**true**)?

Comment: matcher.setCaseSensitive(true) typo mistake. I tried false also and also implement "WebMvcConfigurer" interface but these are not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After @Xiidref solution could you add below.

(If you are using spring-boot, just add this in your property and it will work)

```
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ant_path_matcher
```

in your `application.properties` file.

Answer (score 1):

Since SpringBoot 2.6.x (Spring 5.3.x), `PathPatternParser` becomes the default pattern implement instead of `AntPathMatcher`.

So since SpringBoot 2.6.x (Spring 5.3.x):

```java
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        var paser = new PathPatternParser();
        paser.setCaseSensitive(false);
        configurer.setPatternParser(paser);
    }
}
```

In SpringBoot 2.5.x (Spring 5.2.x) and earlier:

```java
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        AntPathMatcher matcher = new AntPathMatcher();
        matcher.setCaseSensitive(false);
        configurer.setPathMatcher(matcher);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation [AntPathMatcher Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html#setCaseSensitive-boolean-) the boolean of the `setCaseSensitive` should be `false` to get a case insensitive behaviour.

So replace

```java
matcher.setCaseSensitive(true);
```

By

```java
matcher.setCaseSensitive(false);
```

Comment: not work and this class "WebMvcConfigurerAdapter" is also deprecated in springboot 2.6.7

Comment: implement "WebMvcConfigurer" interface instead of "WebMvcConfigurerAdapter" class. @AhmadRaza

Comment: ``
@Configuration

public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override

    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        AntPathMatcher matcher = new AntPathMatcher();
        matcher.setCaseSensitive(false);
        configurer.setPathMatcher(matcher);
    }
}
``
@Shahrukh this also not work